# Should I allow direct connection from an application to data warehouse?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

I am working on an application which needs to get data from a data warehouse.  I was always under the impression that an application should not have direct access to a data warehouse.  With the improvements in data warehousing like Snowflake, RedShift etc is this principle still valid and why?  I can't seem to find much documentation online which says not to give direct access anymore and whether it would differ between internal and external applications.

Also, what is the best way to provide the data to applications from the data warehouse?  Should the application have a a direct connection to a dedicated database/schema in the data warehouse, should a boundary be created like exporting the data they need from the data warehouse to SFTP site for it to be consumed from there or something else.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the impression that "an application should not have direct access to a data warehouse"? That's never been a (common) rule as far as I'm aware and would, in many cases, make a warehouse useless - if you couldn't connect to it

Comment: Hi.  I thought that one of the main reasons this was avoided was because a data warehouse contains a large portion of the organization's data and direct access was a risk as it meant that if the connection for an application was breached then it could access all of this data so measures are taken to reduce the impact and reduce the data that could be visible in a breach by creating boundaries or only providing subset of data and if this is still the case I was interested to see what is best practice today

Comment: You need to create a service account and a specific role for this access, your application will only access the data set this role can access to.

Comment: What is the "application" you mention? Are you referring to an app on a mobile phone, or a desktop app that employees use on their computer while connected to the corporate network, or a web app that is running in AWS that employees access via a web browser? Who are the users of this app and how do they authenticate to the app?

Answer (score 0):

There is the security angle, which demircioglu correct notes, make an account for the app, that has access to just the view's it needs.

Then there is the abstraction angle. If your application is directly access the database, (aka it has SQL in the SQL code/data/config) it is now locked into the shape of the database.

There are 3 ways to deal with this,

1. in a classic RMDBs you would make your App only call stored procedures, so there is no "how" baked into your App, just an interface. Thus everything is flexible. Snowflake has stored procedures (now) so this is an option.
2. write the App to only select from Views. Even though to use a view, you have to have access to the table, developers use discipline to just not read from the tables, thus avoid tightly coupling of the DB from the App release cycle
3. put an Service between the App and the DB, thus the App is now decoupled, and the Service while tightly coupled, is not the DB, and should be owned controlled by the DB team.

Views used to take a while to create, so if you have thousands of views to update this could be slow-ish (to be honest I am not sure, my opinion here is 4+ years old). And you have to trust developers to not "just use the table", and to "share the knowledge" of the why and self enforce.

Store Proc's didn't use to exist, and accessing the results is somewhat painful, compared to something like PostgreSQL, but this might be the cleanest method.

In my old compare we went the Service route, because it already existed on the pre-Snowflake architecture, and thus was easy to re-target Snowflake, and it worked really well, it was also the layer that re-wrote the SQL we got, to use the correct multi-tenanted security layers we were using, and allowed us to change from "user" table to "customer_x_user_view" and later user defined functions, thus "customer id" could be pasted into the deeper SQL so filters were forced down. This also allowed us to have different customers on different releases, as we could leave the v1_views & v1_udf live, while deploying v2_views that used new tables, and if there where problems, we could just swap back to v1 per customer, in that service layer.

Which is heaps more work that most people might want upfront, but it worked really well for us.

Like all trade off, what you should do, depends on what you need, and how much you need, and by when.